# Why am I getting a "duplicate page uri" error when leaving the field blank?

Tags: error, pages, windows, iis

Running EE on windows server and I get the "duplicate page uri" error when editing any entry. I don't want these as pages, but I can't save without creating a unique page url for them...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that page has been added to the Pages module list, it will require a URI. And if you've left at least one other blank, then that's where your duplicate URI is coming in. Just check out the Pages module list and make sure you delete the page from there -- it won't actually remove the page entry in the channel though.

Comment: awesome! Somehow the default placeholder text had been added as a page. Deleted that and now it works perfectly.